How to get user location using the Instagram Graph API?
Today, I see the endpoint https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v20.0/location that retrieves the location of my own page. Is there any way to obtain the location of third-party users, such as those who comment or send private messages directly to my instagram page?
I tried using this endpoint with the IDs of some other users who contacted my page via DM without success. I can see the number of followers, following, username, among other things.
